# where should I install windows?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows, gparted

here is a picture of "GParted".  [image: GParted image]

Where should I install windows (which partition?)?

It's SDA1? I'm not sure because there are 20gb in use and I don't know why. It's possible that's the older version of ubuntu? I chosen in ubuntu installer to install ubuntu 12.04 next to ubuntu 13 but i'm not sure.

Comment: You don't **have** to erase Ubuntu and install Windows first. (At least, not with Win7/bios. I don't know if Win8/EFI changes this). If you are backed up and able to re-install everything, it is certainly _easier_ to install Win7 first and then install Ubuntu. Otherwise, you need a primary, NTFS partition for Windows. You could reformat sda1 as NTFS, leaving sda2/6/5 untouched; or you could shrink sda1, then make a new NTFS partition in the free space. Navigate the Win install menu carefully to make sure Win is only using the NTFS partition, then re-install Grub2 from live media to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that if you want to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu you must install
Windows first in a primary partition, leaving enough free space for Ubuntu.

Your `/dev/sda1` partitions contains `/boot`, that is, the files necessary to boot
your Ubuntu system (i.e., the kernel image).

This means that if you want to install Windows you will have to format your
drive (erasing Ubuntu and everything), install Windows leaving space for Ubuntu,
and then install Ubuntu on the free space left.

After formatting you should create a partition table that looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1 --> primary partition for Windows (say 100 GB)
/dev/sda2 --> extended (say the rest, for example)
```

Inside the extended partition you would install Ubuntu however you wish.
You could use all the remaining space not used on Windows or you could
do something else... like dividing it between Ubuntu and a vfat partition
(to share between both OSs).

If you plan to format your drive, I recommend the following approach:

1. Get Ubuntu's live CD/DVD and burn to a CD/DVD or pendrive.
2. Boot into the live media (CD or DVD or pendrive) and choose 'Try Ubuntu'.
3. Start GParted and erase all the partitions on your hard drive (I am assuming you
   are working with ONE hard drive, you should be careful not to erase valuable
   data).
4. In GParted go to `Device -> Create partition table`
5. Add a primary partition, make sure to set it to an appropriate size
   for your Windows installation (say ~ 100 GB). Leave enough space for  Ubuntu.
6. Add an extended partition, you may want to use up the remaining free space.

Now you can shutdown, remove the live media, and insert your Windows DVD in order to
install Windows on the first partition (the primary one) we created. After installing
Windows, you can shutdown and use the Ubuntu live media to install Ubuntu on the extended
partition.

Comment: Can I change the size of the /dev/sda1? (100GB for windows)

Comment: Yes, you can use as much space as you want. Of course, you must leave enough for Ubuntu (if you plan to dual boot, that is). But as said before you must reformat your disk to install Windows without too much pain.

Comment: Oh, and yes, you can resize `/dev/sda1` to accommodate for Windows...

Comment: @edwin It's not true that Windows must be installed first. It's just _usually_ easier; but if you don't want to delete an existing Ubuntu install, it's not that hard to install Windows later.

Comment: Yes, I noticed later that I was being somewhat closed minded due to my experiences dealing with grub2 configuration (and my rather pronounced willingness to start from scratch!).

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb is to install Windows first on it's own partition and then install Ubuntu on the other so that a menu is created for you...  Installing Windows second is more hassle than it's worth but can be done if you know how to use grub effectively...